# window.onload() is not firing in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, cordova, ratchet

this following code is working in the browser on my PC, but not in my hybrid app built with cordova. I'm using the ratchet framework.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            document.getElementById('cy_username').value = localStorage.getItem('cy_username');
            document.getElementById('cy_password').value = localStorage.getItem('cy_password');

            document.getElementById('settingsForm').addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit, false);

            if (localStorage.getItem('cy_pushNotification') == "true") {
                document.getElementById('cy_pushNotification').classList.add('active');
            }
            if (localStorage.getItem('cy_emailNotification') == "true") {
                document.getElementById('cy_emailNotification').classList.add('active');
            }

            showInfoBox();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**window.load** is only for desktop browser, for hybrid application use,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have this function in my global js file. Can I override it in this single page?

Comment: ya you can do it, it will trigger in the order it is mentioned in the file.